# Iframe in SharePoint 2013 in mobile device will not scroll

Tags: android, ios, css, sharepoint, iframe

I have created a SharePoint 2013 site which has a couple of iframes. When I open the site on a mobile device (have tested on iPad and Android mobile) I can see the iframes and when I try to scroll the entire page by touching within the iframe it doesn't scroll.

I have tried to add this to my CSS:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

to the `<div>` parent container of the iframe but it didn't work.

I have seen a lot of issues regarding scroll within the iframe itself but couldn't find anything related to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I had the exact same problem. Try adding this to your CSS and it should solve the issue.

```
#s4-workspace, iframe { 
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; 
}
```

Comment: OMG. I would upvote this a million times if I could. This is the ONLY thing that has worked for us. Awesome, awesome, awesome. Thanks sixtyfive!